# linear predictor - ordered probit (ordinal, clm)

Tags: r, package, ordinal

I have got a question regarding the `ordinal` package in `R` or specifically regarding the `predict.clm()` function. I would like to calculate the `linear predictor` of an `ordered probit` estimation. With the polr function of the MASS package the linear predictor can be accessed by object$lp. It gives me on value for each line and is in line with what I understand what the linear predictor is  namely X_i'beta. If I however use the `predict.clm(object, newdata,"linear.predictor")` on an ordered probit estimation with clm() I get a list with the elements eta1 and eta2,

1. with one column each, if the newdata contains the dependent variable
2. where each element contains as many columns as levels in the dependent variable, if the newdata doesn't contain the dependent variable

Unfortunately I don't have a clue what that means. Also in the documentations and papers of the author I don't find any information about it. Would one of you be so nice to enlighten me? This would be great.

Cheers,

AK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (after comment):**

Basic `clm` model is defined like this (see [clm tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_tutorial.pdf) for details):

[image]

Generating data:

```
library(ordinal)
set.seed(1)
test.data = data.frame(y=gl(4,5),
                       x=matrix(c(sample(1:4,20,T)+rnorm(20), rnorm(20)), ncol=2))
head(test.data) # two independent variables 
test.data$y     # four levels in y
```

Constructing models:

```
fm.polr <- polr(y ~ x) # using polr
fm.clm  <- clm(y ~ x)  # using clm
```

Now we can access `thetas` and `betas` (see formula above):

```
# Thetas
fm.polr$zeta # using polr
fm.clm$alpha # using clm
# Betas
fm.polr$coefficients # using polr
fm.clm$beta          # using clm
```

Obtaining linear predictors (only parts without `theta` on the right side of the formula):

```
fm.polr$lp                                                 # using polr
apply(test.data[,2:3], 1, function(x) sum(fm.clm$beta*x))  # using clm
```

New data generation:

```
# Contains only independent variables
new.data <- data.frame(x=matrix(c(rnorm(10)+sample(1:4,10,T), rnorm(10)), ncol=2))
new.data[1,] <- c(0,0)  # intentionally for demonstration purpose
new.data
```

There are four types of predictions available for `clm` model. We are interested in `type=linear.prediction`, which returns a list with two matrices: `eta1` and `eta2`. They contain linear predictors for each observation in `new.data`:

```
lp.clm <- predict(fm.clm, new.data, type="linear.predictor")
lp.clm
```

**Note 1:** `eta1` and `eta2` are literally equal. Second is just a rotation of `eta1` by 1 in `j` index. Thus, they leave left side and right side of linear predictor scale opened respectively.

```
all.equal(lp.clm$eta1[,1:3], lp.clm$eta2[,2:4], check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Note 2:** Prediction for first line in `new.data` is equal to `thetas` (as far as we set this line to zeros).

```
all.equal(lp.clm$eta1[1,1:3], fm.clm$alpha, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Note 3:** We can *manually* construct such predictions. For instance, prediction for second line in `new.data`:

```
second.line <- fm.clm$alpha - sum(fm.clm$beta*new.data[2,])
all.equal(lp.clm$eta1[2,1:3], second.line, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Note 4:** If `new.data` contains response variable, then `predict` returns only linear predictor for specified level of `y`. Again we can check it manually:

```
new.data$y <- gl(4,3,length=10)
lp.clm.y <- predict(fm.clm, new.data, type="linear.predictor")
lp.clm.y

lp.manual <- sapply(1:10, function(i) lp.clm$eta1[i,new.data$y[i]])
all.equal(lp.clm.y$eta1, lp.manual)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. this is however not what i was looking for. the question was: what are eta1 and eta2 in the result of predict.clm(object, newdata,"linear.predictor").

Comment: @chameau13: Initially, I didn't get the main point from you question. Please, see updated answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your really extensive explanation! An explanation in words however would have been sufficient ;-). But I think now I get it: It gives you the number by which Xb is over a certain threshold, right? This is what confused be, because polr gives you, when you use $lp, just one column and I guess this is the linear predictor with regard to the chosen category. Merci!