# R: Plotting predictions of MASS polr ordinal model

Tags: r, categorical-data, posthoc, lsmeans

I fitted a proportional odds cumulative logit model on ordinal data using `MASS`'s `polr` function using (in this case on data giving the preference for different kinds of cheese) :

```
data=read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/psj74dx8ohnrdlp/cheese.csv?dl=1")
data$response=factor(data$response, ordered=T) # make response into ordered factor
head(data)
  cheese response count
1      A        1     0
2      A        2     0
3      A        3     1
4      A        4     7
5      A        5     8
6      A        6     8
library(MASS)
fit=polr(response ~ cheese, weights=count, data=data, Hess=TRUE, method="logistic")
```

To plot the predictions of the model I made an effect plot using

```
library(effects)
library(colorRamps)
plot(allEffects(fit),ylab="Response",type="probability",style="stacked",colors=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(9))
```

[image]

I was wondering though if from the predicted means reported by  the `effects` package one could also plot something like the mean preference for each kind of cheese together with the 95% conf intervals on this?

EDIT: originally I also asked about how to obtain Tukey posthoc tests, but in the meantime I found that those can be obtained using

```
library(multcomp)
summary(glht(fit, mcp(cheese = "Tukey")))
```

or using package `lsmeans` as

```
summary(lsmeans(fit, pairwise ~ cheese, adjust="tukey", mode = "linear.predictor"),type="response")
```

Comment: Interesting question. I'm assuming (as you do) that the problem arises because you take the means *after* you created the predicted probabilities. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390080/linear-predictor-ordered-probit-ordinal-clm)  and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/predicting-ordered-logit-in-r/41025#41025) for more on this on SE. Also, with 9 categories, I'd simply go for an OLS on the response variable which produces almost exactly the same point estimates for the mean categories, together w/ sensible standard errors. But it's an interesting question.

Comment: Yes I think it's got to do with averaging on the cumulative logit scale vs on the final backtransformed scale. So basically I would like to know how to average on the link scale and then backtransform to the original ordinal scale. I know that for 9 categories I could also just do OLS, but I would like a general solution also for fewer categories, e.g. 3 or 4.

Comment: dynamite plots (those bar plots) are just bad statistics. You don't gain any more insights than you do from the `wmeans` table of summary statistics. and due to the fact that this _is_ just a plot of summary statistics, you lose all of the data that went into making it. plots should show data not summary statistics. I think this solves your problem since you shouldn't be doing it in the first place

Comment: Well my question is about how to correctly calculated my wmeans table, not about how to best display it... I am well aware of those bar plot haters, which to be honest I never quite understood, especially not in this case where I display everything over the full response scale...

Comment: The main problem is that your trying to summarize non-normal data based on assumptions that require normality.  You could, as you suggested, create the confidence intervals on transformed data and back-transform.  Another alternative, though, would be to simply use non-parametric summaries.  Perhaps your error bars could be the first and third quartiles, for instance.

Comment: Ha Russ Lenth just sent me a message pointing out how to do it, see below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Russ Lenth just kindly pointed out to me that the mean preference and 95% confidence intervals can be obtained simply with `lsmeans` with `option mode="mean"` (`?models`) (the same also applies to a `clm` or `clmm` model fit using package `ordinal`):

```
df=summary(lsmeans(fit, pairwise ~ cheese, mode = "mean"),type="response")$lsmeans
 cheese mean.class        SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A        6.272828 0.1963144 NA  5.888058  6.657597
 B        3.494899 0.2116926 NA  3.079989  3.909809
 C        4.879440 0.2006915 NA  4.486091  5.272788
 D        7.422159 0.1654718 NA  7.097840  7.746478
```

which gives me the plot I was looking for :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(df, aes(cheese, mean.class)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", fill="steelblue", width=0.6) + 
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=asymp.LCL, ymax=asymp.UCL), width=0.15, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
     theme_few(base_size=18) + xlab("Type of cheese") + ylab("Mean preference") + 
     coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 9)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:9)
```

[image]